# C# Dictionary, Sum of value from one key?

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary and use it as a save game.

```
public Dictionary<string, inventoryvars> inventar = new Dictionary<string, inventoryvars>();

public bool Additem(string Planetname, int WWlvl, int AKlvl, int BaGebLvl, int UwLvl, int Exlvl)
{

    inventoryvars ip = new inventoryvars();

    if (!inventar.ContainsKey(Planetname))
    {

        ip.name = Name;

        ip.WWlvl = WWlvl;
        ip.AKlvl = AKlvl;
        ip.UwLvl = UwLvl;
        ip.Exlvl = Exlvl;

        inventar.Add(name, ip);

        return true;

    }
    else
    {

            inventar[name].anzahl += 1;

        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now i need to get the sum of all Exlvl. Lets say, there are 5 items, every item has Exlvl with a different value.

Sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

The Solution is: inventar.Sum(x => x.Value.BaGebLvl);

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Why are you always returning "True" ?

Comment: inventar.Sum(x => x.Value.Exlvl)

Comment: @Ghost2k20 Do you want a sum for the `Exlvl` for `x` number of items with the same type? Or are you trying to sum all item types `Exlvl`? Some sample data and expected results may clarify your post.

Comment: i want a sum of all Exlvl. Like, if there 5 Items.

Item 1: Exlvl = 5;
Item 2: Exlvl = 3;
Item 3: Exlvl = 7;
Item 4: Exlvl = 10;
Item 5: Exlvl = 6;

Now i need the sum.

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve the result?

Comment: I've tried the solution from Tahul and 
                 ExLVLsum = inventar.Where(item => inventar.ContainsKey(item.Key)).Sum(item => itms[i].Exlvl); But i don't get the result i wat. It counts 0,2,4,6,8 and doesn't use simple addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Values` property to get all instances of `inventoryvars` and use LINQ `Sum()` against them

```
var result = inventar.Values.Sum(x => x.Exlvl)
```

(OR)

```
var result = inventar.Sum(x => x.Value.Exlvl)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it returns only 0,2,4, etc. and doesn't sum the values of Exlvl.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a funtion that return the sum of keys in your collection?
public int sumOfKeysValues(public Dictionary input)
{   int result = 0;
    foreach(var item in input)
    { 
      var key = (inventoryvars)item.key;

```
   result += key.Exlvl;
}
```

}